# Why isn't an intersection of two different literals equal to never?

Tags: typescript, types

```
type T = 1 & '2';
const a: T = ???
```

There is no value that could possibly be assigned to `a`, yet `T` is `1 & "2"`, not `never`, even in strict mode. Why?

Comment: You can use a type assertion to fool the compiler that a value has type `T`. It is surely of limited use, but my guess is that nobody implemented `1 & '2'` to be `never` and it does not follow from any other type rule.

Comment: I think I've had this conversation before... https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16386#issuecomment-328836063

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I happened to recently file [an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25730) asking about this.  The answer was that an error that something isn't assignable to `1 & '2'` tends to be more helpful than an error that something isn't assignable to `never`:

> The inconsistency here is because intersections are only reduced when used in a union. so `"foo" & "bar"` will stay that type unless it is part of a union. that is why `x` is not assignable to `u`.
>
> We have found that keeping the intersections longer gives better error messages to users, since `never` can does not tell you where the type originated from. more over, there is something to say about user typing a type as such, what the intent is..

Comment: One could argue that a lot of intersections might not be assignable, for example without an assertion all primitive intersections are not directly assignable ex: `string & number` or `string & boolean`